# read specific elements on a list wih R

Tags: r, list

I have the following list:

```
v1<-c('hello', 'bye')
v2<-c(1,2,3)
v3<-c(5,6,5,5,5,5)
l<-list(v1, v2, v3)
```

I want to read the second element of each member of the list. Thus the result may be:

```
 'bye' 2 6
```

I did it using 'sapply' with the instruction:

```
sapply(1:3, function(i){l[[i]][2])
```

and it works. But I would like to do it with an easier instruction, I tried

```
 l[[1:3]][2]
```

But it doesn't work. Which is the easier way to obtain the second element of each member in my list.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

```
sapply(l,`[[`,2)
#[1] "bye" "2"   "6"
```

**EDIT:**

Note that result of this operation is a vector, so all elements had to be coerced to the same type (in this case, it is `character`). If you'd like to keep the types of the result components, you should use

```
lapply(l,`[[`,2)
```

which returns a list, and elements of a list in R could be of different types. (thanks to Richard for bringing attention to this aspect!)

Comment: `lapply()` might be more appropriate because of the different types.

Comment: For users who are not familiar with the extraction operators, see `help('Extract')` for details.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to do it directly from the list without using sapply?

Comment: Yes.  Make it into a data frame first

Answer (score 0):

If you want to vectorize this (avoid `*apply` loops), you could use `stringi::stri_list2matrix` (though, you will lose your classes)

```
library(stringi)
stri_list2matrix(l, byrow = TRUE)[, 2]
## [1] "bye" "2"   "6"
```